# On average what length power loss will trigger a microprocessor to reset?

Tags: voltage, microprocessor

Given a recently manufactured microprocessor operating at 3.3v from such standard manufacturers such as Intel, AMD, Samsung, Qualcomm, Broadcom, etc, how long would a loss of power need to be before the chip is guaranteed to reset? A nanosecond, a picosecond, a femtosecond? Something else?

Comment: If you actively discharge the 3.3V rail to near zero volts, I don't think the time matters. Assuming the chip has internal power on reset circuitry, you can be 100% sure it will reset when the rail comes back up. If you NEED to reset it, you should take the rail down to zero with an active discharge. If you need to prevent reset, you should plan on NO excursion of any duration below VCC min.

Comment: RESET occurs when the Reset line is pulled into the must_reset zone for >= min_reset_time. Brown out occurs when brown out conditions trigger the BOD - usually on the power rails. 
Processors are INTENDED to not corrupt registers or operate wrongly for transitions that the BOD does not catch BUT Murphy was an optimist. | A good question is "What do you REALLY want to know?" You are probably more interested in whether feasible but unlikely events will cause havoc or wish to ensure that they don't (or do :-) ). Knowing what you REALLY want may help

Comment: Note that *very* short loss of power may be covered by the decoupling capacitors next to the chip.

Answer (score 2):

you should check the datasheet - they typically specify it in the Brownout Detection section.

the general answer is that it should be considered "instantaneous" for practical purposes.

obviously, having some energy storage and anti-bleed devices (caps, diode / resistor, inductors) on the rail will help prolong that time.

Comment: @satur9nine A BOD may incorporate a filter so that **a Vdd glitch** must last longer than 1 uS (min), 5 uS (max) to initiate a BOD. I'd hope that internal parasitic SCRs inherent in all CMOS take longer to latch and cause mayhem. *Example taken from PIC16F1454 data sheet.*

Answer (score 2):

The microprocessor itself generally will not reset- it will have results corrupted or whatever. A glitch of just about any length, if it gets into the internals, is sufficient to cause disruption. Even if the glitch is within tolerable power supply variation (for slow variations) if it is very short it could cause disruption.

Many modern microcontrollers (and probably some microprocessors) have peripherals on board that are intended to generate a reset upon a power supply event. It is up to the designer to make sure that the power the micro gets is such that the onboard peripheral can generate a reset pulse when appropriate, every time, or to use an external reset circuit (in which case the internal peripheral could be disabled to save power or for other reasons).

A well-designed reset circuit will detect a power supply drop and generate a pulse of sufficient length to ensure a complete and proper reset once the power has returned to normal. Often the length of the pulse is in the hundreds of milliseconds. Again, it is up to the designer to make sure that the power cannot drop out for a really short time that would not be detected by the reset circuit but would cause disruption of the micro. This normally is done by having sufficient bypass capacitance and not having really heavy loads on the same supply.

Comment: But surely if power is down for something very long, say a minute, and then re-applied the processor will be fully reset and will boot without needing any reset pulse?

Comment: @satur9nine, 
Most processors have internal power-on reset (POR) circuitry. If they do, they will usually take care of reset. There may be some out there that don't have their own internal POR, and rely on receiving a valid reset pulse prior to boot. If it needs a reset pulse, the datasheet will say so.

Comment: @satur9nine, for any power loss the result will depend on the ratio between internal power consumption, and the amount/value of bypass capacitors soldered on particular platform. The consumed power, however, depends on the current processor mode/state. If it is in deep sleep and consumes a fraction of microampere, the state can stay unperturbed for hours.

Comment: @satur9nine usually, yes, if the power is reapplied cleanly. If the power stutters as it comes uo you could start off badly. A lot of consumer products have bad reset circuits and assume the user will notice and will just cycle the power in that case, but there are applications where the reset should be as bulletproof as possible.